# Group Managed Service Account - Permanent Password?

Tags: active-directory, managed-service-accounts

Is there a way to manually manage gMSA (Group Managed Service Account) passwords?
Usually gMSA passwords are managed by Active Directory, but sometimes I need to manually manage the password (to use for example in external systems for ldap binding, etc.).

I know I could just use a regular user account, but if I can use gMSA, I'd be able to limit the account from logging in interactively to domain computers. 
And yes- I know I could limit the users from logging in interactively with GPO, but gMSA would be simpler, and more ironclad than GPO (I can misconfigure the GPO by mistake). Besides, less GPO's == faster boot \ login..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to set a gMSA to not change its password. That's the whole point of the MANAGED part